# click event on ajax loaded content and dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

I have load content using ajax. need to call on ajax loaded content. i have also try some code but no luck with this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var itemId = '<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>';

         jQuery("#cart-sidebar").on("click", '.increment_qty_'+itemId, function(event) {
            console.log("work");
        });

        jQuery("#cart-sidebar").on("click", '.increment_qty_<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', function(event) {
            console.log("work");
        });
});
```

Comment: what is your problem? and where is you ajax call here?

Comment: You're getting `itemId` when the page is first loaded, it doesn't come from AJAX. Is AJAX really returning elements with that `itemId`, or does that change dynamically?

Comment: yes i have every time got itemId but this click event js also loaded on ajax success

Comment: when ajax call its replace full file content with above js. after page refresh click event work good

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the events to document, this ensures that whenever the element is found in DOM it can be fired

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var itemId = '<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>';

          jQuery(document).on("#cart-sidebar","click", '.increment_qty_'+itemId, function(event) {
            console.log("work");
        });

        jQuery(document).on("#cart-sidebar","click", '.increment_qty_<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', function(event) {
            console.log("work");
        });
});
```

Comment: can you post a little html of yours?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to attach event handlers to content loaded by Ajax.

1. Attach the event on the **done callback** of the ajax request. (ref: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

   ```
   $.ajax({
        url: "xyz.php",
   })
   .done(function( content ) {
       $("#cart-sidebar").on("click", '.increment_qty_'+itemId, function(event) {
              console.log("work");
        });
   });
   ```
2. Use [Event Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). This will allow you to attach event listeners to elements **even in the future**.

Comment: not possible to set  1 option because js file and ajax are two different file

Answer (score 0):

Just do like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var itemId = '<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>';

         jQuery(document).on("click", '.increment_qty_'+itemId, function(event) {
            console.log("work");
        });


});
```

Comment: @Ajaypatel use document instead of $("#cart-sidebar").on("click", as i mentioned in my answer. Also please mentioned the way you are dynamic adding html

Comment: i have all try document, live, on, delegate, but not work because js loaded on ajax